# bootstrap-slider not working despite scripts begin in correct order

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

My `<head>` tag has:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
...
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
...
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="ex4" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="-3" data-slider-orientation="vertical"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#ex4").slider({
        reversed: true
    });
});
```

... All I see is an input text box with rounded corners. I suspect that jQuery-ui is overriding the slider command here so I've also tried this JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#ex4").bootstrapSlider();
});
```

.... and I see nothing. The DOM loads new HTML but none of it is visible. There is no CSS hiding any of this, but the heights of the elements are all `0` and after manually setting these heights to higher numbers in the CSS, they are still not visible:

```
<div class="slider slider-vertical" id="">
   <div class="slider-track">
      <div class="slider-track-low" style="top: 0px; height: 0%;"></div>
      <div class="slider-selection" style="top: 0%; height: 8%;"></div>
      <div class="slider-track-high" style="bottom: 0px; height: 92%;"></div>
      <div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" tabindex="0" style="top: 8%;"></div>
      <div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round hide" tabindex="0" style="top: 0%;"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltip tooltip-main right" style="left: 100%; top: 8%; margin-top: -11.5px;">
      <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
      <div class="tooltip-inner">-3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltip tooltip-min right" style="left: 100%;">
      <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
      <div class="tooltip-inner"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltip tooltip-max right" style="left: 100%;">
      <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
      <div class="tooltip-inner"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

***I can even click around in this empty space in random places and see the values for the slider change in the inspector!!!*** The other answers to questions like this include putting scripts in the correct order, which I have done. Is there a version mismatch somewhere?

There are no console errors and no resources fail to load.

I am using jQuery v 3.3.1 and bootstrap v 3.3.7.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? Check your network tab as well to see if all the resources are loaded properly.

Comment: There are no console errors and no resources fail to load.

Comment: Create an actual jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good to me, but I notice in your head element you have a bootstrap-slider.js file without a corresponding .css file. Is there one available to you that you're not including?